# How to replace \begin{markdown}...\end{markdown} with \md{...}?

Tags: macros, environments, markdown

I am trying to replace the `\begin{markdown}...\end{markdown}` idiom with `\markdown{...}` to save some keystrokes, but I get a "runaway argument" error and No PDF.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{markdown}
\newcommand\md[1]{\begin{markdown}#1\end{markdown}}

\title{markdown test}
\author{Goo Bar}
\date{May 2023}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{markdown}
Hello world
\end{markdown}

\md{Goodbye world}

\end{document}
```

Replacing `markdown` with `abstract` works fine, so the idea should work in practice. What am I missing with the `markdown` package?

Comment: markdown is a verbatim -like command so giving it a command argument syntax is tricky and would remove functionality. your editor should let you make `\begin{markdown} \end{markdown}` in a couple of keystrokes

Comment: This is never a good idea. Firstly the code becomes harder to read secondly it is not all constructions that are allowed inside a macro, verbatim like data comes to mind. Thus if you find `\begin{markdown}...\end{markdown}` cumbersome to type, define a shortcut in your editor.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle indeed, the begin/end version takes 5 keystrokes (`\ b enter m enter`) compared to 4 for my version (`\ m d {`), just a 20% improvement. Luckily I learned something new about the markdown package by asking this question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't: `\begin{markdown}` sets up things so that

- some category code are changed;
- lines are processed one by one;
- processing is stopped when the ***string*** `\end{markdown}` is scanned.

As you surely know, leading and trailing spaces are significant in Markdown, but they aren't for TeX: under the standard settings, leading spaces on a line of input are ignored and trailing spaces are discarded and replaced by the `\endlinechar`. Thus in the `markdown` environment the standard settings about spaces have to be changed.

If you do

```
\newcommand{\md}[1]{\begin{markdown}#1\end{markdown}}
```

none of the three points above can be salvaged, because when TeX absorbs an argument it fixes the category codes and no longer has a notion of the endlines that could be present in the argument. Well, there are tricks that could help to get a somewhat functional command version of the environment, but now consider this: can you see a clear advantage of

```
\md{You can't: `\begin{markdown}` sets up things so that

* some category code are changed;
* lines are processed one by one;
* processing is stopped when the ***string*** `\end{markdown}` is scanned.

}
```

over

```
\begin{markdown}
You can't: `\begin{markdown}` sets up things so that

* some category code are changed;
* lines are processed one by one;
* processing is stopped when the ***string*** `\end{markdown}` is scanned.
\end{markdown}
```

in case of longer input?